# Unable to install Ubuntu - getting ignoring BGRT and ACPI probe failed

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia

I have i7 3770k, 16gb RAM, and an Nvidia 900 series graphics card.

I am not able to install ubuntu on my computer because when I select install from the USB, I get issue that Ignoring BGRT invalid status 0 (expected 1) and ACPI PCC probe failed.

Not sure what to do.  Nothing seems to be working.  I do not have an OS on this machine.  Please help because I tried to use google but the solutions are not working.

Comment: The BGRT is an ACPI table that provides a pointer to the UEFI boot graphics logo.  The warning is saying the table isn't instantiated by the firmware properly.

Comment: Please try to boot Ubuntu with the `noacpi` kernel parameter set.  [This page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions) describes how you can accomplish that.